# wordpress page template is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on theme and i want to create page template may code is below :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

<div class="left">

<div class="pagina">

</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have creat page name Blog and assign it a custom template from dropdown Blog,But when I click on navigation element Blog it shows `The requested URL /wp/blog/ was not found on this server.`

anyone can help?

Comment: which code I have missded?

Comment: if you are talking about html then leave that's not the problem I have skipped it

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with your permalinks?

Comment: maybe..  but don't know how to solve this

Comment: I have just add Blog in menu , didn't do anything else....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest this is a permalink issue, not a template issue. Your .htaccess file should be writable and you should have some code automatically added to it when you set up the permalinks. Check that it is writable and try setting the permalinks up again. Failing that, I believe that WordPress gives you the code to copy/paste into it when you're setting up the permalinks.

In short, add this code to your .htaccess file, if it's not there already.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I think you need to follow the article on http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks - I'll add the .htaccess code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That could be one of many reasons; either you have a blog template or it could be because you have not included the loop:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives with Content
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div class="left">
        <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div class="entrytext">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    <!-- and whatever else you need -->
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If that still does not work, try refreshing your permalinks

Comment: how I can refresh permalinks?

Comment: WordPress admin | Settings | Permalinks | and simply Save Changes

That should sort out your problem and if there is a permission issue, an error message will be dislayed after clicking "Sav Changes"